# python subprocess output with quota cmd

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, quota

1I am trying to get the result of quota command via ssh into python, I am using:

```
cmd = 'quota -gsl user1'
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        cmd,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        timeout=5,
        shell=True,
        universal_newlines=True
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    exit()
```

this works fine if user1 is within quota and it returns something like

```
Disk quotas for group user1 (gid 9999): 
     Filesystem   space   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sda2    666M  10240M  12560M            1141       0       0
```

but if the user is over quota, it does NOT return

```
Disk quotas for group user1 (gid 9999): 
     Filesystem   space   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sda2    11000M*  10240M  12560M            1141       0       0
```

but only `False` for `output`. This is even the case when I use `quota -q` which returns a simpler output only for over quota. I also tried this with `quota -gslq 2>&1` but it did not work, and I thought `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,` should already deal with this. So why cant i get the result for over quota users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoth [the manpage for `quota`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/quota):

> **Diagnostics**
> If quota exits with a non-zero status, one or more filesystems are over quota.

You're using `check_output`, which combines `check_call()` (which errors out when the command returns a non-zero status) and `getoutput()` (which doesn't check the error code).

You may wish to use the [`getstatusoutput()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) shorthand:

```
status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput("quota -gsl user1")
```

or to spell it out with your original invocation (if e.g. the timeout is important),

```
cmd = 'quota -gsl user1'
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        cmd,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        timeout=5,
        shell=True,
        universal_newlines=True
    )
    status = 0
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    status = e.returncode
    output = e.output
print(status, output)
```